# How to fill the gridview in Android based on grid position?

Tags: android, gridview

I would like to fill the grid view with some user controls based on the positions in Android with java code. For example in a grid of 8 rows and 8 columns, lets say I would like to fill the user control in Row1 X Column1 and lets say I would like to fill the user control in Row3 X Col4 etc., Means some Row X Columns I would like to fill empty and some with the controls. How can we do this with a grid view. Or can we do in another way to do the same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the array with some indexes having data and some with empty data. or have some boolean values in ur array. on the basis of these boolean values u can populate data in the grid using ur adapter.